# Is my proof correct (normal operator)?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Q. Let V be a $n-$dimensional space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T$ a normal operator. Prove that all T-invariant space is $T^{*}$-invariant.

A. If $T$ is normal over $\mathbb{C}$ then $V$ admit a basis of eigenvectors of $T$ such that $V$ is a direct sum of $E_{i}$, $i=1,...,k$ where $E_{i}$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda_{i}$. $E_{i}$ is $T-$invariant so if i prove that $E_{i}$ is $T^{*}-$invariant the result follow.

is that correct?

Comment: Well, correct.. but.. perhaps this statement to prove is implicitly used in the theorem you want to apply..

Comment: the Theorem that if $T$ is normal than $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Don't worry. You can prove that normal matrices are diagonalizable without reference to invariance. By the Schur decomposition, every matrix is unitarily similar to an upper triangular matrix. But a simple calculation from the definition of normal shows that diagonal matrices are the only normal upper triangular matrices. This applies to linear operators by means of any basis.